# Azure B2C security groups authorization

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-webapps

I'm trying to use  example where I was able to update custom policies mentioned in this example and deployed REST API mentioned.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Net;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using AADB2C.RBAC.Sample.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using System.Net.Http;


namespace AADB2C.RBAC.Sample.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class IdentityController : Controller
    {
        private readonly AppSettingsModel AppSettings;

        // Demo: Inject an instance of an AppSettingsModel class into the constructor of the consuming class, 
        // and let dependency injection handle the rest
        public IdentityController(IOptions<AppSettingsModel> appSettings)
        {
            this.AppSettings = appSettings.Value;
        }

        [HttpPost(Name = "IsMemberOf")]
        public async Task<ActionResult> IsMemberOf()
        {
            string input = null;

            // If not data came in, then return
            if (this.Request.Body == null)
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new B2CResponseModel("Request content is null", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
            }

            //Read the input claims from the request body
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(Request.Body, Encoding.UTF8))
            {
                input = await reader.ReadToEndAsync();
            }

            //string input = Request.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;

            //string content = "";
            //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;
            //using (var reader = new StreamReader(
            //         Request.InputStream, System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, true, 4096, true))
            //{
            //    content = reader.ReadToEnd();
            //}
            ////Rest
            //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Request.InputStream.Position = 0;

            // Check input content value
            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(input))
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new B2CResponseModel("Request content is empty", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
            }

            // Convert the input string into InputClaimsModel object
            InputClaimsModel inputClaims = InputClaimsModel.Parse(input);

            if (inputClaims == null)
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new B2CResponseModel("Can not deserialize input claims", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
            }

            if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputClaims.objectId))
            {
                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new B2CResponseModel("User 'objectId' is null or empty", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
            }


            try
            {
                AzureADGraphClient azureADGraphClient = new AzureADGraphClient(this.AppSettings.Tenant, this.AppSettings.ClientId, this.AppSettings.ClientSecret);

                // Demo: Get user's groups
                GraphGroupsModel groups = await azureADGraphClient.GetUserGroup(inputClaims.objectId);

                // Demo: Add the groups to string collections
                List<string> groupsList = new List<string>();
                foreach (var item in groups.value)
                {
                    groupsList.Add(item.displayName);
                }

                // Demo: Set the output claims
                OutputClaimsModel output = new OutputClaimsModel() { groups = groupsList };

                // Demo: Check if user needs to be a member of a security group
                if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(inputClaims.onlyMembersOf))
                {
                    List<string> onlyMembersOf = inputClaims.onlyMembersOf.ToLower().Split(',').ToList<string>();
                    bool isMemberOf = false;
                    foreach (var item in output.groups)
                    {
                        if (onlyMembersOf.Contains(item.ToLower()))
                        {
                            isMemberOf = true;
                            break;
                        }
                    }

                    // Demo: Throw error if user is not member of one of the security groups
                    if (isMemberOf == false)
                    {
                        return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new B2CResponseModel("You are not authorized to sign-in to this application.", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
                    }
                }

                // Demo: Return the groups collection
                return Ok(output);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                if (ex.Message.Contains("Request_ResourceNotFound"))
                {
                    return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new B2CResponseModel("Can not read user groups, user not found", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
                }

                return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new B2CResponseModel("Can not read user groups", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
            }

        }

    }
}
```

So I have reached point where custom policy uses REST POST method to get the groups details but this code mentioned doesn't provide me group details as it goes to catch statement and throws can not read user groups.The problem here is I cannot use localhost to run the Rest API and hit the API through custom policy ,I tried using proxy but it gives me bad request.

```
return StatusCode((int)HttpStatusCode.Conflict, new B2CResponseModel("Can not read user groups", HttpStatusCode.Conflict));
```

Any help or example would be very helpful

Comment: Hello, could you please show us some more code, or some elements avoiding us to rely on the links.

Answer (score 0):

Web app code is in the source code folder in the linked repo.

Comment: code repo has Rest API written /api/Identity which is used as service url in custom policy but webapp is missing where we can use signin/singup for user to run the user flow.

Comment: You can use any of the samples here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/code-samples

Comment: I have updated the description @Jas Suri ,pls let me know if you have any suggestion for this